# Verifying Trello Webhook signature

Tags: security, go, hmac, trello, hmacsha1

I am having trouble successfully verifying a webhook request from Trello. Here's what I know.

Trello's webhook documentation [here](https://developers.trello.com/apis/webhooks) states:

> Each webhook trigger contains the HTTP header X-Trello-Webhook. The header is a base64 digest of an HMAC-SHA1 hash. The hashed content is the concatenation of the full request body and the callbackURL exactly as it was provided during webhook creation. The key used to sign this text is your application’s secret.

Which is understandable. They go on to say

> Because of certain defaults in the crypto utilities in node, the payloads that we sign are treated as binary strings, not utf-8. For example, if you take the en-dash character (U+2013 or 8211 in decimal), and create a binary buffer out of it in Node, it will show up as a buffer of [19], which are the 8 least significant bits of 8211. That is the value that is being used in the digest to compute the SHA-1.

This is less clear to me. My understanding is that each character of the payload (body + callbackURL) has been put into an 8-bit integer, with the overflow ignored. (Because 8211 == 0b10000000010011, and 0b00010011 == 19) This is where I think my problem is.

The function I am using to accommodate Trello's node payload issue is:

```go
func bitShift(s string) []byte {
    var byteString []byte

    // For each rune in the string
    for _, c := range s {

        // Create a byte slice
        b := []byte(string(c))

        // Take the sign off the least significant byte
        tmp := b[len(b)-1] << 1
        tmp = tmp >> 1

        // Append it to the byte string
        byteString = append(byteString, tmp)
    }
    return byteString
}
```

It is also very possible that I am doing something wrong with the basic verification step. It looks okay to me, though I am somewhat new to this.

```go
// VerifyNotificationHeader ...
func VerifyNotificationHeader(signedHeader, trelloAPISecret string, requestURL *url.URL, body []byte) bool {

    // Put callbackURL and body into byte slice
    urlBytes := bitShift(requestURL.String())
    bitBody := bitShift(string(body))

    // Sign, hash, and encode the payload
    secret := []byte(trelloAPISecret)
    keyHMAC := hmac.New(sha1.New, secret)
    keyHMAC.Write(append(bitBody, urlBytes...))
    signedHMAC := keyHMAC.Sum(nil)
    base64signedHMAC := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signedHMAC)

    if comp := strings.EqualFold(base64signedHMAC, signedHeader); !comp {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you!

**Update**: This is solved, check out the answers.

Comment: Do you have an example request and signature that we could match ?

Comment: Thanks for the interest! If I cannot get this working in the next day or two I will add all the information needed to test these functions. At the moment I am reluctant to create a new Trello account for the sole purpose of sharing the secret here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you throwing away the MSB? You're converting each `rune` to `byte`, which is signless (and actually an alias for `uint8`), so that bit holds information that you're losing.

You might consider using a function like this instead:

```
func ascii(s string) []byte {
    var ret []byte
    for _, r := range s {
        ret = append(ret, byte(r))
    }
    return ret
}
```

Since `rune` is an alias for `int32`, the cast to `byte` just drops the top 24 bits, which is what you want.

(Caveat: this assumes little-endianness.)

Comment: I was trying to do something like this and was getting overflow errors, which is why `bitShift` is the way it is. This is much cleaner! Thanks! But I think they have the same output, right?

Comment: On an en-dash, yes, because bit 7 (zero-indexed) is zero, but not for anything with that bit set. `bitShift` throws that bit out, but `ascii` preserves it. For instance, `bitShift(0b10001110)` yields `0b00001110`, where `ascii(0b10001110)` just gives you back the byte unchanged: `0b10001110`.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the reason `bitShift` is giving 63 there rather than 255 is the cast directly to `string` from `rune`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, 0xff me. You're right. I had been looking at strings [cast as byte slices](https://play.golang.org/p/BqLgsEDEdf) because I was getting confused by the errors I got from other attempts.  I'll put this in!

Comment: @doykle: note that this is only OK if you're guaranteed to not have any non-utf8 bytes in your data. When go transforms a string to runes, any invalid utf8 is converted to the unicode replacement character 0xfffd. http://play.golang.org/p/0gNumZzJ_V . I have no idea what the behavior of the node libraries would be in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems with my code. The major issue was my use of `requestURL.String()` for the `callbackURL`.

In the [comments](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) above `http.Request.URL`:

> For most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be empty.

It turned out that `requestURL.String()` was only giving the `[Path]` portion of `[Scheme]://[Host][Path]`. The correct callbackURL is

```
callbackURL := "https://" + request.Host + request.URL.String()
```

The second problem was pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215799/4006407), where the verification would have failed for any request whose body contained 8th-bit-having characters.